# Access Query - Summing Month to Date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I currently have a crosstab query set up to return amounts by month in 2017. This displays month totals for each location individually. I want to sum year to date (month 1-7) and have it only return one value for the location. I am having trouble doing this for some reason.

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Location.Amt) AS SumOfAmt
SELECT 
    Location.Div
  , Location.Store
  , Location.Year
  , Location.Month
FROM 
  [Location Name] 
  INNER JOIN Location 
    ON [Location Name].Line = Location.Line
WHERE 
  (
    Location.Store     <> 100 
    AND Location.Year   = 2017 
    AND Location.Month  < 8 
    AND Location.Line   < 11
GROUP BY 
  Location.Div
  , Location.Store
  , Location.Year
  , Location.Month
ORDER BY 
  Location.Div
  , Location.Store
  , [Location Name].LineDesc
PIVOT [Location Name].LineDesc
;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `select` and `group by` clauses you've listed `Year` and `Month` which means it will aggregate for each value in those columns. If you don't want that behavior, you should remove those columns from the query.

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Location.Amt) AS SumOfAmt
SELECT 
    Location.Div
  , Location.Store
FROM 
  [Location Name] 
  INNER JOIN Location 
    ON [Location Name].Line = Location.Line
WHERE 
  (
    Location.Store     <> 100 
    AND Location.Year   = 2017 
    AND Location.Month  < 8 
    AND Location.Line   < 11
GROUP BY 
  Location.Div
  , Location.Store
ORDER BY 
  Location.Div
  , Location.Store
  , [Location Name].LineDesc
PIVOT [Location Name].LineDesc
;
```